# Fetched vs computed values in Terraform data sources

Tags: terraform

According to Terraform docs, data sources can be used to fetch or compute values by using different provider implementations.

Ref. - https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

What exactly is the computed vs. fetched distinction, preferrably in a concrete example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The docs are saying that instead of hardcoding some value you could instead ask Terraform to go get that value from somewhere else. So this could be getting the VPC ID for a specific VPC or it could be returning a list of IP addresses to whitelist or any number of things that might need to be calculated/retrieved at run time instead of being hardcoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction is slight:

At a high level, **fetched** data exists before you run your template and **computed** data is created during runtime.

Fetched data would be similar to the example in the reference.  Here `Terraform` is fetching information about an AMI which can then be used to build out an EC2 instance:

```
data "aws_ami" "web" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Component"
    values = ["web"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}
```

Computed data could generally be defined as data that doesn't exist before Terraform starts but will be generated (computed) as your template proceeds.  For example if you were to create an EIP to use with an EC2 instance you would run:

```
resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
}
```

From that, several bits of information will be `computed` as the EIP is created:

```
+ aws_eip.ip
    allocation_id:     "<computed>"
    association_id:    "<computed>"
    domain:            "<computed>"
    instance:          "${aws_instance.example.id}"
    network_interface: "<computed>"
    private_ip:        "<computed>"
    public_ip:         "<computed>"
```

You could then use those `computed` values in other resources.  e.g. passing `aws_eip.ip.public_ip` to a security group for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense! If only the Terraform docs were so revealing.